# Nodejs best way to read xlsx as utf8 text

Tags: node.js, xlsx

I need to read xlsx in nodejs. Xlsx contains text with accents and apostrophes and so on. Then i have to save the text in json file.

What are the best practices to perform that task?

Comment: Use [a package](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)?

Answer (score 2):

1. Stage 1 - take a look at this module [node-xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-xlsx) or more robust and possibly better for your needs [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx).
2. Stage 2 - Writing the file to JSON - if the module can return a JSON format then great. If you use [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) it has an option to JSON --> [take a look here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#json).
3. Since you may need to actually strip and/or protect special accents etc. you may need to validate the data which is returned before producing a JSON file.
4. As to actually writing a JSON file, there are a huge amount of NPM modules for the task.

Comment: Is there any way to read excel data to JSON with utf-8 encoding, I need this because of the issue as in https://support.overloop.com/en/articles/3343526-i-see-weird-symbols-when-opening-a-csv-export-file-in-microsoft-excel-2007